# What kind of/family of (real) $N\times N$ matrix has unique (real) $n$ eigenvalues (spectral theorem does't guarantee uniqueness)

Tags: matrices

I'm wondering what kind of/family of $N\times N$ (real) matrix has unique(distinct) $N$ (real) eigenvalues.
The spectral theorem doesn't guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: By unique, do you mean distinct?

Comment: Yes, distinct eigenvalues

Comment: You could rule out any group as the set could not contain the identity matrix (except in the 1d case)

Comment: I think we need to add "some condition" on the symmetric matrix since the spectral theorem has "almost" what I need but just uniqueness/distinct.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the family of simple matrices

Comment: Not necessarily true. Take a diagonal matrix with two terms on the diagonal being the same. The eigenvalues would not be distinct in this case.

Comment: I think that what you are talking about would be a semi-simple matrix. A simple matrix (by definition) is matrix with distinct eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0):

It can be characterized as the complement zero set of a polynomial $p$ on the matrix entries.

A matrix has district eigenvalues (over $\mathbb{C}$) if and only if its characteristic polynomial has distinct roots. Hence take $p$ to be the [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant#Definition) of the characteristic polynomial.

PS: In algebraic geometry, this is called a Zariski open set. This is very useful, because it means that this matrices are *generic*, i.e. almost all matrices are of this form. Sometimes it is enough to prove a theorem for generic matrices in order to see that is true for all of them. For example, check [this proof](https://aergus.net/blog/posts/using-zariski-topology-to-prove-the-cayley-hamilton-theorem.html) of the Cayley-Hamilton theorem.